# Excel VLOOKUP returning #N/A when values are present

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am creating a spreadsheet for a school sports event, whereby points are awarded based upon the time/distance/height/etc. achieved by each student.  The reference data table denotes the points available for each event but does not include every value – i.e. points correlate to a range of values.  For example: x points awarded for a distance between 1.00m and 1.04m; y points for a distance between 1.05 and 1.09; etc.  The ranges are not consistent.  Users will enter the exact time/distance/height/etc. for each student into the spreadsheet and a formula should automatically calculate the points score.

I am using a nested `IF(COUNTIF(VLOOKUP` formula to:

1. Search the reference data table for the value entered (e.g. 2.18), and if present, return the point value.  If not present…
2. …reduce the value by 0.01 (i.e. 2.17) and try again, returning the point value if present.  If not present…
3. …reduce the value by 0.02 (i.e. 2.16) and try again, returning the point value if present.  If not present…
4. …reduce the value by 0.03 (i.e. 2.15) and try again…
5. …Etc. until a value is returned.  The largest range is 0.05, so no more than 5 cycles.

   =IF(COUNTIF(Distance,D4),VLOOKUP(D4,$A$4:$B$13,2,FALSE),IF(COUNTIF(Distance,D4-0.01),VLOOKUP(D4-0.01,$A$4:$B$13,2,FALSE),IF(COUNTIF(Distance,D4-0.02),VLOOKUP(D4-0.02,$A$4:$B$13,2,FALSE),IF(COUNTIF(Distance,D4-0.03),VLOOKUP(D4-0.03,$A$4:$B$13,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(D4-0.04,$A$4:$B$13,2,FALSE)))))

The formula appears to work, however upon testing, a number of values return #N/A, despite a match being present.  There appears no pattern to those which return #N/A.  Using formula evaluation and error checking do not help provide answers.  I have tried all the usual tricks – ensuring formatting (text/number/general) is consistent; checking for spaces, validating the value in formula is exactly the value in the VLOOKUP table – all appears normal and correct, yet #N/A values are still returned randomly.
Link to image of data below.
Any ideas on what is going on, or if there is a more eloquent formula?

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQfV2.png)

Comment: An issue that you may be having is that for VLookup to work the table you are searching must be in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using the `index`, `Match`, and `VLookup`.  Below is the code I've used that looks up the closest value and finds a match in the second row. (you may need to change the table names and list names.

`=INDEX(Table_Points,MATCH(VLOOKUP(B2,Table_Points,List_Points,TRUE),List_Points,0),2)`

**EDIT (this code should work for your exact workbook sample as long as you change the lookup table to be ascending with the smallest number and points on top):**

`=INDEX($A$4:$B$13,MATCH(VLOOKUP(D4,$A$4:$B$13,1),$A$4:$A$13),2)`

Where Table_Points is the whole table (distance and points) and List_Points is just the list of distances.

[image]

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks - this works great and much more elegant.  Still curious as to what the problem was beforehand - why the #N/A was returned.

Comment: I was looking at it and couldn't figure it out either after testing it.  If you think this answer was good it would be nice to have an upvote to signal to others it was helpful.  Glad I could help!

Comment: I've tried, but as a new user it says my upvotes don't get displayed yet.  Thanks for your help